# Adding mosaic layer to ArcMap using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, mosaic

I have a mosaic layer that I want to add to my map in ArcMap. When I add this layer manually (i.e the "Add Data" button), a raster image, a boundary, and a footprint are added to my table of contents. However, when I run the following code, only the raster image is added to my TOC. I have no idea why this happens.

How do I get my code to also add the footprint and boundary to the map?

```
    import arcpy
    in_workspace = r"C:\Users\Christian\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb"
    in_mosaicdataset_name = "mosaic_file"
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
    path_to_layer = in_workspace+"\\"+in_mosaicdataset_name
    layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(path_to_layer)
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df,layer,"BOTTOM")
```

Answer (score 2):

As originally edited into the question by its asker (who has not been on the site for two years):

> Michael Miles-Stimson's idea worked. The following code produced the
>   desired result:
>
> ```
>     import arcpy
>     arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Christian\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb"
>     in_mosaicdataset_name = "mosaic_file"
>     mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
>     arcpy.MakeMosaicLayer_management(in_mosaicdataset_name,in_mosaicdataset_name+"_layer")
>     arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(in_mosaicdataset_name+"_layer",in_mosaicdataset_name+"_layer.lyr")
>     layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(in_mosaicdataset_name+"_layer")
>     df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
>     arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df,layer,"BOTTOM")
> ```